# How to Integer overflowed value when Integer is drived from Integer.parseInt("2147483647");

Tags: java, integer, integer-overflow, numberformatexception

Lets consider below lines of code.

```
1- int ExA = Integer.parseInt("123");
2- int ExB = Integer.parseInt("2147483660");
```

if we execute line 1 than variable ExA will be successfully populated by 123

but if we execute line 2 than we will "NumberFormatException" because in line 2 number provided to the 'parseInt' function is beyond int range.

I am looking for a solution where I can get overflowed int value if we have a number in string format whose value is beyond int range. Please help me figuring out.

Comment: By overflow in value, you mean the difference between the max possible int and the given value?

Comment: Err, `long`? and `Long.parseLong()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use BigInteger instead.

`BigInteger ExB = new BigInteger("2147483660");`

Regarding JDK docs,

> BigInteger must support values in the range -2^Integer.MAX_VALUE
>   (exclusive) to +2^Integer.MAX_VALUE (exclusive) and may support values
>   outside of that range. The range of probable prime values is limited
>   and may be less than the full supported positive range of BigInteger.
>   The range must be at least 1 to 2^500000000

Comment: its not just about BigInteger or long value consider I have string like this - "342342342342342342423442121333123" which is beyond any data type range.

Comment: then it's better to store it as a string and make some algorithm to add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc. but it will be much more complicated.

Comment: @Farhan why do you think that's beyond the type range of BigInteger?  And  why do you think it's better to write your own code than to use BigInteger?

Comment: @Farhan `"342342342342342342423442121333123"` is *not* beyond the range of `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger is sometimes messy to implement. You could have a `long`, and just do `Long.parseLong("2147483660")`, if it doesn't exceed 2^64.